# How do I install python-mode.el for Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat). I have downloaded `python-mode.el` from [Launchpad](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Launchpad) and placed it in `emacs.d/plugins/`.

Now how do I install `python-mode.el`?

Comment: Hasn't python-mode been standard since emacs 22?

Comment: The "python-mode" here is a separate package from the default "python" mode that ships with FSF emacs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins")
(require 'python-mode)
```

Comment: How do you know what name to require ?

Comment: @murtaza52 - it's generally the name of the .el file, but not always.  if you open the .el file, near the end there should be a line like `(provide 'python-mode)` which indicates the name you need to `require`.

Comment: Just to add a little to what @jtahlborn said, (require) loads a feature and (provide) says what features a ".el" file is making available.

Comment: Can you add this information to the answer instead of using comments?

Answer (score 3):

I find it more convenient to have the appropriate editing mode auto-load based on the type of file edited. There are lots of ways to do this, but I usually add an entry to autoload-alist:

```
(and (library-loadable-p "python-mode")
     (setq auto-mode-alist (append '(
                     ("\\.py\\'"       . python-mode)
                     )
                   auto-mode-alist)))
```

I have a long list of these for the various modes I like to use. It fails silently if python-mode (or any other mode) is not installed. If I'm running on an ISP sever that doesn't have a mode installed, I add ~/lib/elisp to the load-path and put the missing .el files in there.

library-loadable-p came from a friend and simply tests whether the file is somewhere in the load path:

```
(defun library-loadable-p (lib &optional nosuffix)
  "Return t if library LIB is found in load-path.
Optional NOSUFFIX means don't try appending standard .elc and .el suffixes."
  (let ((path load-path)
    elt)
    (catch 'lib-found
      (while (car path)
    (setq elt (car path))
    (and
     (if nosuffix
         (file-exists-p (concat elt "/" lib))
       (or (file-exists-p (concat elt "/" lib ".elc"))
           (file-exists-p (concat elt "/" lib ".el"))
           (file-exists-p (concat elt "/" lib))))
     (throw 'lib-found t))
    (setq path (cdr path))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest cloning the latest snapshot:

```
cd ~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/python-mode
bzr branch lp:python-mode
```

Then add to `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/python-mode")
(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/python-mode")
(require 'python-mode)
```

You can later update the to the latest version with:

```
bzr update
```

But don't forget to re-compile:

```
(byte-recompile-directory (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/python-mode") 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In emacs 25, you can install python mode using melpa, so just add this to your .emacs file:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
```

Reload the file, then type,

```
Alt+x list-packages
```

Move to the package you want,

```
python-mode
```

Then hit "enter", and in the new buffer that opens move to `Install` and press enter.

This causes python-mode to be installed in `~/.emacs.d/elpa`

Now in a new buffer with `python-mode` on, write your code and type `C-u C-c C-c` to evaluate and display output.